# COM: javascript/jquery method for creating a xml data file from SharePoint list data (multiple)

Tags: javascript, client-object-model, jquery, xml

Does anyone know how I can pull off creating an xml data file from data in multiple lists using SPServices/Javascript/jQuery? I can certainly bring all the data I need out to a page and load into DOM or whatever if needed. Just not sure if there is a way without having SOM development capability to create the xml file. Either in a doc library, or windows dialog to store on the local machine (client machine)? anything?

Thanks for any and all help as always!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think to save the file you would need something like [Downloadify](https://github.com/dcneiner/Downloadify)

Getting the XML depends if you want it custom formatted etc.

You could just use Javascript to call the lists.asmx yourself

or

Do it as office does it and go [FrontPage RPC](http://salaudeen.blogspot.co.uk/2012/02/using-owssvrdll-to-retrieve-list-data.html)

If you want custom, then you could build it in the DOM for ease and then export to a string variable, then downloadify it.

Comment: thanks Hugh. the FrontPage RPC is actually the kind of thing I was looking for....just unaware that I could approach it this way. Thanks very much!

Answer (score 0):

I have seen this topic on the SPServices forums before and underatood that it is possible to create ASCII files from the browser using webservices (although I have not had the need to do it myself).  You will need the help of a BASE64 javascript library to do it.